# What is the procedure for Agnishtoma ritual that leads to Heaven?

Tags: scripture, rituals, yajna, vedic-gods, vedic-rituals

**Agnishtoma** is a Vedic ritual that takes its name from three hymns to Agni recited in it and was performed by those who want to ascend to heaven. This Hindupedia page - **[Agniṣṭoma](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Agni%E1%B9%A3%E1%B9%ADoma)** gives the basic steps of the ritual but the reference given for that is a book by Swami Harshananda not any specific scripture.

**Can anyone share the detailed procedure for the same from the scriptures?**

Comment: I believe is almost lost. There are brahmins in karnataka resurging agnishtoma. This is not a proper answer, but maybe help, sorry [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RYvkYk7GvJ0](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RYvkYk7GvJ0)

Comment: Oh that's sad. Shouldn't it be mentioned in some text related to rituals?

Comment: [Agnishtoma Soma Yagam in Kerala after 222 years](https://www.hindu-blog.com/2009/04/agnishtoma-soma-yagam-in-kerala-after.html) . Or [maybe you can ask here](https://www.meetup.com/es/Srividya-Personal-Spiritual-Growth-Meditation-Healing/events/246465354/?eventId=246465354&chapter_analytics_code=UA-3773779-1)

Comment: And [here](http://veda.wikidot.com/kalpa-vedanga) says that in _SHUKLA YAJURVEDIYA KALPASUTRA "_From the seventh chapter to the tenth chapter there is a complete description of 'AGNISHTOMA YAGYA'. The seventh and eighth chapter contain the various ceremonies which are performed prior to the performance of 'AGNISHTOMA YAGYA', the ninth chapter contains the various rituals performed during the early morning and the tenth chapter describes about the various rituals performed during the noon time and during the evening time._" . But I didn't research more, so I don't know